# Access activity log in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace

In Google Drive I can view **past activity** for a folder like below.

Is there any way I can access this information, in a data format, to be able to abalyze the information?

Preferebly I would like to access the activty data for a specific folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

one can query the [revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list) for a file with the  API:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/revisions
```

use [Libraries for Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/) to request by `fileId` and get the revisions as `JSON`; one just has to share with the service account's email address (non-interactive) - or use the client-side `oAuth2` flow, so that the script will act on behalf of the user (interactive).